# What is necessary to connect Python to Oracle Database

Tags: python, sql, oracle, toad, cx-oracle

I have been trying to connect Python 3.7.1 to TOAD 11, with a client version 10.2.
When I try running the code below

```
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('myusername/mypassword@orcl')

cursor = connection.cursor()

querystring = "select * from TABLE_NAME"

cursor.execute(querystring)
```

I get the following error:

DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "C:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\CLIENT_1\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

I have been trying to download a 64 bit client, but I don't understand why I need one since TOAD and it's current client are 32-bit. The issue is that with my company, it does not say the bits in the description whenever something is requested to be installed (due to the security in the network, I cannot download anything unless it is approved by the IT department, and it can only be downloaded through their server). I attempted to download the instant client 11g, but it seems it was installed but the 10.2 version it's still the only one I can find in my machine. I cannot see where it is located anywhere, so I cannot even set an environment variable for it, but I can see it in the "uninstall wizard", but it doesn't show it's location. I don't even know if 11g is 64 bit or 32 bit.

Has anybody fixed this problem before?
Is my code off and maybe that's why its not working?

Comment: From my point of view, you're mistaken. You don't connect to TOAD, but to an Oracle database. TOAD is a tool used to access it (the database); why would Python connect to it? Anyway: even if I'm right, I can't help - I don't use Python.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying you need a 64-bit Oracle Client because Python is 64-bit.

For cx_Oracle you need Oracle client libraries version 11.2 or later.  You can get the libraries as part of Oracle Instant Client from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html  On Windows you will also need the Redistributable noted on that download page.

Also see the cx_Oracle installation instructions at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows

You will have to work with your IT people to make this happen.